# In Java Collections Map<Key,?> What does "?" refer to?

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashmap

In Java Collections I saw something like this: `Map<Key,?>`.
I don't know how it is working, can anyone help me out with this or provide an example?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The question mark (?) represents an unknown type.

In your example, `Map<Key, ?>`, it means that it will **match** a map containing values of any type. It **does not** mean you can create a `Map<Key, ?>` and insert values of any type in it.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

> In generic code, the question mark (?), called the wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable; sometimes as a return type (though it is better programming practice to be more specific). The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype.

For example, say you want to create a function that will print the values of any map, regardless of the value types:

```
static void printMapValues(Map<String, ?> myMap) {
    for (Object value : myMap.values()) {
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
}
```

Then call this function passing a `Map<String, Integer>` as argument:

```
Map<String, Integer> myIntMap = new HashMap<>();
myIntMap.put("a", 1);
myIntMap.put("b", 2);
printMapValues(myIntMap);
```

And you would get:

```
1 2
```

The wildcard allows you to call the **same function** passing a `Map<String, String>`, or any other value type, as argument:

```
Map<String, String> myStrMap = new HashMap<>();
myStrMap.put("a", "one");
myStrMap.put("b", "two");
printMapValues(myStrMap);
```

Result:

```
one two
```

This wildcard is called **unbounded**, since it gives no information about the type. There are a couple of scenarios where you may want to use the unbounded wildcard:

- If you're calling no methods except those defined in the `Object` class.
- When you're using methods that don't depend on the the type parameter, such as `Map.size()` or `List.clear()`.

A wildcard can be unbounded, upper bounded, or lower bounded:

- `List<?>` is an example of an **unbounded wildcard**. It represents a list of elements of unknown type.
- `List<? extends Number>` is an example of an **upper bounded wildcard**. It matches a `List` of type `Number`, as well as its subtypes, such as `Integer` or `Double`.
- `List<? super Integer>` is an example of a **lower bounded wildcard**. It matches a `List` of type `Integer`, as well as its supertypes, `Number` and `Object`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explain and examples!

Answer (score 1):

## The Unknown Wildcard

`?` can be any dataType

`List<?>` means a list typed to an unknown type , This could be a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Boolean>`, a `List<String>` etc.

Now coming to your example `Map<Key,?>` means `Value` which is to be inserted in this map can be of any data Type.